# Best practice for config variables in front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx

I'm trying to deploy my Node.js + React.js web application in AWS. I've got defined several constants with url's, for example, which will have a value in my environment and other in AWS environment.

To do this in backend I use the file .env with the module "dot-env" and I can define a variable depending if it's for development environment or production environment.

But, I don't know how to do this for the front-end because after I have tried to use the module "dotenv" in the front-end, but during compiling I've got an error, so I can't use this module to do the same in front-end than in the back-end.

So, what is the best way to define variables depending of the environment to the front-end?

Comment: Are you deploying front and back end separately? If so, you can add environment variables to be used during the build process (e.g., `API_URL=http://foo.bar yarn build`)

Comment: Yes, I'm deploying separetly. Front-end will be served by nginx.

Comment: If you're using `create-react-app`, there's a bit of nuance to how you have to format your environment variables: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Comment: And how can I access to this variables?

Comment: OK, I can do it like I do in the backend with process.env.NAME_VARIABLE. Thank you @Nick!!!

Comment: In your code they can be referenced as `process.env.API_URL` where the last part is your environment variable. Then when the site is being built, node will put your env variable there

Comment: You should read this [article](https://blog.container-solutions.com/deploying-configurable-frontend-web-application-containers), if you use webpack, docker and nginx.